# How to Seralize non-generic IList with Objects with XMLSerializer

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I'm trying to Serialize some Object, that contain an `IList` with Children Elements. The `IList`is non-generic and i cannot just make it at generic one.
I get the exception like "The Type MyObjectChild was not expected. ..." and it says something about XMLInclude, but i don't think thats what I'm searching.
Does anyone have any idea how bring `XMLSerialzer` to serialize the child elements as well?
Both Elements are `[Serializable]`

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof ObservableCollection<MyEntryViewItem>));
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(exportPath, FileMode.Create);

xmlSerializer.Serialize(fileStream, _listEntries);

public IList ElementChildren { get { return _item.Children; } set { _item.Children = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => ElementChildren); } }

[Serializable]
public sealed class ElementChild
{
    private int _id;
    private string _text;
    private string _path;
    ...
}
```

Comment: You are trying to serialize a collection of MyEntryViewItem, what is this class?  Also the error refers to another clas you haven't put into context, MyObjectChild.  I think more information would help alot!

Comment: It's just a basic Class with some propertys (mostly strings) that i want to serialize. But one of the propertys is an IList with Elements of Type ElementChild...

Comment: MyObjectChild is the same as ElementChild... i mixed up the names...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Simon Hewitt](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8644/XmlSerializer-and-not-expected-Inherited-Types) you can just use the `XmlInclude` to specify the type of your list. An alternative can be found at [roboxman.wordpress.com](http://robboxman.wordpress.com/2008/10/02/solving-the-%E2%80%9Cxmlserializer-and-not-expected-inherited-types%E2%80%9D-problem-without-implementing-ixmlserializable/)

Answer (score 0):

XmlSerializer treats IList in special way(actually ICollection and IEnumerable, but IList is both). There is note on [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) MSDN page:

> The XmlSerializer gives special treatment to classes that
>   implement IEnumerable or ICollection. A class that implements
>   IEnumerable must implement a public Add method that takes a single
>   parameter. The Add method's parameter must be of the same type as is
>   returned from the Current property on the value returned from
>   GetEnumerator, or one of that type's bases. A class that implements
>   ICollection (such as CollectionBase) in addition to IEnumerable must
>   have a public Item indexed property (indexer in C#) that takes an
>   integer, and it must have a public Count property of type integer. The
>   parameter to the Add method must be the same type as is returned from
>   the Item property, or one of that type's bases. For classes
>   implementing ICollection, values to be serialized will be retrieved
>   from the indexed Item property, not by calling GetEnumerator.